# Array not playing back properly inside function - bubble sort

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm learning how to do bubble sort on arrays right now in c++. I have done most of the work, but now in my function which prints the array, the last number in the array is being replaced with a garbage number.
I suspect it has to do with the for loop in the function not properly 'playing back' the array, but I'm not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void showArray(int sortMe[], int size);

int main()
{

int sortMe[4] = {10, 2, 3, 1}; // Original Array
int numElements = 4;
int temp; // For swapping
cout << "Before sort: ";
showArray(sortMe, numElements);

for (int i=numElements-1; i>0; i--) { // For loop1

    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        // Checks if the value on left is bigger than the right
        if(sortMe[j] > sortMe[j+1]) {
            // If bigger swap values
            temp = sortMe[j];
            sortMe[j] = sortMe[j+1];
            sortMe[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
    cout << "After sort: ";
    showArray(sortMe, numElements);

}

void showArray(int sortMe[], int size) {
    // Outputs array in format array = {num1, num2, etc.}
    int i;
    cout << "Array = {";
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        cout << sortMe[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << sortMe[i] << "}" << endl;

}
```

The output I get with this is:

```
Before sort: Array = {10, 2, 3, 11867600}
After sort: Array = {1, 2, 3, 1}

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.101 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: In showArray, `for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)` ==> `for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)` - note the removal of the leading `int`, which causes a local var decl and thus leaves the outer `int i;` indeterminate and untouched. Using it as an index invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: @WhozCraig That comment was different when I started typing my answer, wasn't it? Otherwise, sorry, I was convinced of creating a separate answer....

Comment: @Yunnosch there was a different comment from someone else; it's gone now.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah OK. I was wondering because I was not convinced of that comment and did not expect somethign like that from you. But my conscience is free of gullt for copying from you, I was already typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `ShowArray`, you seem to expect that here

```
cout << sortMe[i] << "}" << endl;
```

`i` is equal to size-1.
It is not, because the counter `i` for the loop is only existing withing the loop.
This is because of these two lines creating an outer and an inner  `i`:

```
int i; // outer i

for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) { // inner i
```

The inner `i` is the counter, ending up on `size-1`, but ceasing to exist immediately.
The outer `i` is the one you use in

```
cout << sortMe[i] << "}" << endl;
```

and it is not initialised. When you access the value you get undefined behaviour.
That is why you get garbage.

Comment: That really helps, thank you! One problem I'm still having is that, despite the numbers being fixed, the second time it outputs it omits the 0 in the 10. I get an output of:
Before sort: Array = {10, 2, 3, 10}
After sort: Array = {1, 2, 3, 1}

Any ideas?

Comment: That is a new question. Please create it as such and I think I will be able to help. It will make thinkgs easier, because we can work on the different code (with the problem from this question fixed), without guessing at how exactly you changed the code shown here.