# The numbers in my bubble sort array output incorrectly after being sorted

Tags: c++, arrays

I am learning bubble sort. In my output array, the numbers in my presort array output correctly, but the second time it outputs with the sorted numbers it omits the 0 in the 10. I get an output of: Before sort: Array = {10, 2, 3, 1} After sort: Array = {1, 2, 3, 1} Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void showArray(int sortMe[], int size);

int main()
{

int sortMe[4] = {10, 2, 3, 1}; // Original Array
int numElements = 4;
int temp; // For swapping
cout << "Before sort: ";
showArray(sortMe, numElements);

for (int i=numElements-1; i>0; i--) { // For loop1
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        // Checks if the value on left is bigger than the right
        if(sortMe[j] > sortMe[j+1]) {
            // If bigger swap values
            temp = sortMe[j];
            sortMe[j] = sortMe[j+1];
            sortMe[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
    cout << "After sort: ";
    showArray(sortMe, numElements);

}

void showArray(int sortMe[], int size) {
    // Outputs array in format array = {num1, num2, etc.}
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Array = {";
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        cout << sortMe[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << sortMe[i] << "}" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You still have the same bug as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892412/array-not-playing-back-properly-inside-function-bubble-sort), whose answer you accepted. You've replaced an indeterminate value with zero, but you still have two `i`s in different scopes.

Comment: Your `showArray` function has off by one error inside the loop. The condition variable should have `size` instead of `size -1`, which leads one element less printing. After the loop you print first element again. Because loop variable `i` has local scope to the loop.

Comment: By the way, the above code give `10, 2, 3, 10` in initial output. Given that initial output print the first number twice (at the beginning as expected and at the end instead of last item), it is easy to know that the bug is in printing code. Once you know that, it is easy to know what will be printed after sorting if sorting works. Using a debugger might also be really helpful for tracing code.

Comment: change

`for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)`

to

`for (; i < size - 1; i++)`
Because in the way you wrote the loop you introduce a new `i` which is destructed once the scope of the loop has gone and the the old `i` will be used again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not the sorting, but printing. You define `i` two times.
If you rewrite your for loop inside the print like this your problem is solved `for (; i < size - 1; i++)`.

The way you've written it the last element is always the element at index `0` because of `int i = 0;` outside of the loop.